# Nodejs with Mongoose returns one object value instead of multiple in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```
data=[{
       locId: '332wn',
       locadetails: [
                    { loc: 'ny',
                      status: true
                    },
                     { loc: 'ca',
                      status: null
                    },
                    { loc: 'tx',
                      status: null
                    }
                  ]
                 }]
```

I have following query that is trying to find all the locdetails that have open value as null or false

```
Loc.find({'locId': id}, {'locadetails' : {$elemMatch: {'status': {$ne: true}}}}, (err, locs)=>{
       if(err) {
          retrun callback(err);
         }
         callback(null, locs)
      });
```

Problem I have is this query will only return one value o locadetails with null while it should return two as seen in the data. 
Please let me know what to do so I can get whole array of items that have status field as null or false ...Thanks

Comment: [`Model.find`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) only takes the first parameter as the query conditions. Try changing it to `Loc.find({ 'locId': id, 'locadetails': { $elemMatch: { 'status': { $ne: true } } } }, callback)`.

Comment: tried it didn't work

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood the question. I can see that you were expecting `Model.find` to work similar to `db.collection.find`, with the second argument being the projection. As I'm not sure of the answer myself, I can only suggest what should work with Mongoose: `Loc.find({ 'locId': id }).elemMatch('locadetails', { 'status': { $ne: true } }).exec(callback)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$elemMatch` will return first matching element from an array based on a condition. Use [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) instead.

> Both the $ operator and the $elemMatch operator project the first
>   matching element from an array based on a condition. [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#usage-considerations)

```
Loc.aggregate([
    { $match: { "locId": "332wn" } },
    { $unwind: "$locadetails" },
    { $match: { "locadetails.status": { $ne: true } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", locId: { $first: "$locId" }, locadetails: { $push: "$locadetails" }, } }
])
```